# How to only show results if count if more than 5

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is it possible to only show results where by the  same cust-num appears more than 3 times.

I have tried using a variable ( count = count + 1.). but its counting all the results .

```
      icount = kcount + 1.
   display
cust-name cust-num state count
```

```
Cust Num Name   State   Count
1001     Apple  NH  1
1001     Apple  NH  2
1001     Apple  NH  3
1002     Orange BD  6
1002     Orange BD  7
1002     Orange BD  8
1002     Orange BD  9

Expected            

Cust Num    Name    State   Count
1001            Apple   NH  1
1002            Orange  BD  2
```

Comment: Check this question and its answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/54476465/2189922

Comment: oh thank you. I didn't see this,  i will definitely check this out and use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first you probably need a temp-table like this:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCust LIKE customer
    FIELD count AS INTEGER.
```

Then, remove that code you posted and add this:

```
FIND FIRST ttCust WHERE ttCust.cust-num = customer.cust-num NO-ERROR.
IF NOT AVAILABLE ttCust then DO:
   CREATE ttCust.
   BUFFER-COPY customer TO ttCust. /* Copies the whole record to your temp-table */
END.
ASSIGN ttCust.count = ttCust.count + 1.
```

And after the END of your regular FOR EACH customer, add this:

```
FOR EACH ttCust where ttCust.count >= 3:
    DISPLAY ttCust.cust-num ttCust.name ttCust.state ttCust.count.
END.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much,  this was really useful